# Is there a colloquial word for 'bro'?

Tags: translation, slang

I know 弟弟 and 哥哥, but I've also heard something like 大哥 being used and I've also been referred to as 兄弟 when someone younger than me greeted me。 Are there any other variants? And which one is most used casually when referring to your mates?

Eng. example: 'Bro, did you watch the latest X', 'Bruh I don't think you're supposed to do X' or just a simple 'What's up bro'.

Comment: You can call him "老兄/弟", or just his nickname.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use 哥们(儿) or 兄弟 in casual speech. E.g. 兄弟，不能这样啊！

But there might be some other variants too like 老兄，老弟，老哥, etc based on the context.

Comment: The 老 here isn't referring to the fact they're older right? Only the 弟 and 哥, are about age, correct?

Comment: @Zheng-rongCai That's correct.

Comment: @Zheng-rongCai even 哥 and 弟 are not that meaningful in terms of age. You can call anyone 老哥 or 大哥  at your similar age.

Comment: Wait, do you say 哥们(儿) for one person too?